# How do you UPDATE a CLOB with large values using only PL/SQL without modifying the DB schema?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Say you had an Oracle 10g (10.2.0.3) database scheme which you cannot modify (as it is not under your control), and you want to insert large strings (100k+ characters) into some CLOB fields for testing purposes using PL/SQL (to be more precise: An SQL script which can be executed via sqlplus through a batch file). Is it possible?

I have found several solutions using .NET, oci etc or creating a stored procedure, but I need a solution which works e.g. from within SQL Developer, without doing any modifications to the DB scheme like adding stored procedures etc.

I have tried it in several ways like e.g.

```
-- Disclaimer: I typed this by heart just for SO, there might be syntax errors
DECLARE
  v_test CLOB;
  v_clob_to_update CLOB;
BEGIN

  -- Note: rpad only works up to 32755 or something
  v_test := to_clob( rpad( 'This is a very long string', 30000, '.' ) );
  v_test := v_test || to_clob( rpad( '.', 30000, '.' ) );

  SELECT my_clob_field INTO v_clob_to_update FROM my_table WHERE my_id = 1234 FOR UPDATE;
  DBMS_LOB.WRITE( v_clob_to_update, LENGTH( v_test ), 1, v_test );
END;
```

but I always end up getting "string literal too long" or "numeric or value error" messages.

Is it possible to do this while respecting the limitations I'm given?

Comment: How about using `DBMS_LOB.WRITE()` or `WRITEAPPEND()` in a loop? Alternatively, you can use `LOADFROMFILE()`.

Comment: Many examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_lob_ops.htm#ADLOB1021)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `dbms_lob` package to write to `v_test`, you should get past the error that you're getting.  The string concatenation operator `||` hasn't been overloaded to handle `LOB` data.

In other words, rather than

```
v_test := v_test || to_clob( rpad( '.', 30000, '.' ) );
```

you probably want

```
dbms_lob.writeAppend( v_test, 30000, rpad( '.', 30000, '.' ) );
```

Comment: Looks promising, I'll try that later today